# Where do you put your engines in your Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been putting them in the toplevel. I am wondering if it is more logical to put them in lib. Is there a general consensus or convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vendor/engines` is my default choice.

Answer (score 2):

I generally make them gems (by creating them with the `bundle gem` command) and keep them as [separate projects](http://github.com/radar/forem) on GitHub. Then I can include them into my application like this:

```
gem 'forem', :git => "git://github.com/radar/forem"
```

This way, I can make commits to my application and have them be separate to the commits for my engine.

The reasoning for doing it this way is because the engine may be shared across multiple applications and I'd rather not have to make the same change multiple times.

Comment: I like this idea, I'm not sure where to put them too, but this is very smart choice ^_^